# Scan works for regex, but doesn't capture full output

Tags: regex

It seems that when I try to "group" my matches, I am only presented with the keywords I'm looking for rather than the entire matching.

For example, here's my sample output:

```
Nmap scan report for scanme.nmap.org ([external-ip])
Host is up (0.082s latency).
Other addresses for scanme.nmap.org (not scanned): 2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe18:bb2f
Not shown: 992 closed tcp ports (reset)
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp    open     ssh
25/tcp    filtered smtp
80/tcp    filtered http
135/tcp   filtered msrpc
139/tcp   filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp   filtered microsoft-ds
9929/tcp  open     nping-echo
31337/tcp open     Elite

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
# Nmap done at Tue Oct 11 01:08:22 2022 -- 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.31 seconds

Nmap scan report for scanme.nmap.org ([external-ip])
Host is up (0.082s latency).
Other addresses for scanme.nmap.org (not scanned): 2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe18:bb2f
Not shown: 992 closed tcp ports (reset)
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp    open     ssh
25/tcp    filtered smtp
80/tcp    filtered http
135/tcp   filtered msrpc
139/tcp   filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp   filtered microsoft-ds
9929/tcp  open     nping-echo
31337/tcp open     Elite

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
# Nmap done at Tue Oct 11 01:08:22 2022 -- 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.31 seconds
```

What I am specifically looking for is how to start from "Nmap scan report for scanme.nmap.org" all the way to the line before "Read data" and match this if it contains 31337/tcp and/or 22/tcp. Next "match", same thing. So essentially I would be able to call output[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtd25.jpg) or output[2] because my sample output contains 2 "groups" and both groups matches one or more of my keywords.

With a regular expression of `Nmap scan report for scanme.nmap.org.*?(22|31337)\/tcp.*?(?=Read data|Nmap scan)` and using `output.scan(/#{regexp}/m)`, I am only getting the following:

```
22
22
```

Rather than an array containing 2 elements, which would match 31337/tcp OR 22/tcp in each group.

If I use `.match(/#{regexp}/m)`, then this *sorta* works. It gets me 1 match rather than 2.

### Edit

With updated regex, I'd like to group these multiple "matches" into an array like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made a small modification to your regex: I escaped the dots too. I also added a new set of parenthesis in the final look-ahead.

Note: be careful that the "dot" MUST match new lines too - i.e., the entire text must be treated as a single line.

```
Nmap scan report for scanme\.nmap\.org.*?(22|31337)\/tcp.*?(?=(Read data|Nmap scan))
```

Use the following regex to skip trailing spaces:

```
Nmap scan report for scanme\.nmap\.org.*?(22|31337)\/tcp.*?(?=(\s*Read data|\s*Nmap scan))
```

And to capture the entire "paragraph" if there is a match:

```
(Nmap scan report for scanme\.nmap\.org[^#]*?(22|31337)\/tcp.*?)(?=(\s*Read data|\s*Nmap scan))
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/vpM3JO/1).

Comment: Thanks. For some reason calling `.match` on this only returns 1 match in Ruby, and calling .scan on this only returns `[["22", "Read data"], ["22", "Read data"]]`. On regex101 it looks like it's returning 2 matches but 1 match in Ruby. Perhaps it's a little different in Ruby to be able to print 2 matches with .match?

Comment: Try to understand how regexes work in Ruby. Unfortunately, I do not have the experience to help you there.

Comment: What do you want to actually catch? both "22" and "31337"? If yes, then the regex must change. This regex catches both: Nmap scan report for scanme\.nmap\.org.*?(22|31337)\/tcp.*?(22|31337)\/tcp.*?(?=(Read data|Nmap scan))

Comment: Yeah exactly. I'd like to be able to go "does the first output starting from Nmap all the way to Read data contain 22/tcp and/or 31337/tcp opened? ok then give me the full output 1 time. does the 2nd output starting from Nmap all the way to Read data contain 22/tcp and/or 31337/tcp open? ok then give me the full output of this" which would equate to 2 array items with the full output because they both match 31337/tcp and/or 22/tcp. The current regex seems to give me bits and pieces (e.g. [["22"]]) rather than the full output.

Comment: I made an update, please see.